# Weight of magnetic objects and polarization

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, gravity, weight

I am an Iranian engineer and have a question which no one has answered me yet.
In weighing a strong magnet, there is a difference between the weights from different polarization directions, why is this? Is the effect it gravitational? I have researched during my life as the article ‘electro-gravitational effect‘.

Would you please find that and tell me about its accuracy or inaccuracy. If that will be correct, then is it possible that a detailed article to be confirmed and published by you?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/116886/

Comment: This site is not a site for publishing or discussing new theories. It is a site for standard physics questions and answers within it

Answer (score 1):

If the weighing device is very accurate you will see a difference in weight as it aligns with, or repels the Earth's magnetic field. Although conventionally people talk of the Earth's field as being "North or South" in much of the world, especially in high latitudes, the field has a strong vertical component

Comment: dear sir/madam according to the magnetic flow ; earth magnetic field applies only Torque to the magnet and not any force

Comment: It depends on how accurately you measure, because there is also a divergence over any given distance. Also, the torque may show up as a differential mass depending on how good (or bad) your balance is. Then there are screening effects of the balance itself, and any diamagnetic/paramagnetic properties of the balance materials to take into account.